# Lookup field requires value even though it and the lookup list are set to not required

Tags: lookup-column

I have two lists and one field is a lookup to a field in the other.  At one time, the list being looked up had "required" turned on.  Even though I am certain it's turned off in both lists for this field, Sharepoint is not allowing me to leave the field blank.  '' is not a valid value for this field is the error I receive when I leave it blank.  It also won't accept a space.  The field is a single line of text.
Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this or what I can put in the field that it will accept?

Comment: Can you share the screenshots of column settings for both the columns? Are you using SharePoint default forms or any custom forms?